# Camera opens on clicking anywhere rather than on button

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

Image for button 500x500.

I have created an `ImageButton` and when `ImageButton` is clicked the system camera should launch and the image brought from the system's camera app will be shown in the `ImageView`. But, the problem is: the button doesn't work here. Other than button if I click anywhere in the app the system camera launches but in case of button click the camera doesn't launch. What kind of error is causing this unexpected behaviour?

**Java File:**

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        //          CAMERA BUTTON IMPLEMENTATION
        ImageButton cameraButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                    /* Disable the button if the user doesn't have camera */

        if(!hasCamera())
            cameraButton.setEnabled(false);
        //          CAMERA BUTTON IMPLEMENTATION
    }

    // Check if the user has a camera

    private boolean hasCamera(){
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
}

    // Launching the camera
    public void launchCamera(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //Take a picture and pass results along to onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    // If you want to return the image taken
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //Get the photo
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); 
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }


}
```

**XML FILE:**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.muchmore.www.chasquido.Home"
    android:background="@drawable/home_background"
    android:id="@+id/home_activity"
    android:onClick="launchCamera">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome User!!!"
    android:id="@+id/welcome_tag"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="#000"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:background="@drawable/camera_button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:minHeight="300dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned `OnClickListener` `android:onClick="launchCamera"` to your `RelativeLayout` (your root view) instead to your `ImageButton`.